# How can i upload csv file to database in php and fix my errors?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to upload a csv file into the database,
but only first line gets inserted and it's still insert a blank space for the first field and shift all the other record.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
             {
            $e1 = $filesop[0];
            $e2 = $filesop[1]; 
            $e3 = $filesop[2]; 
            $e4 = $filesop[3]; 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO eyfstb(e1,e2,e3,e4) values ('$e1','$e2','$e3','$e4')";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db,$sql);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

             $c = $c + 1;
            }

             if($sql){
            echo "sucess";
            } 
             else
             {
             echo "Sorry! Unable to import the data.";
            }

        }
?>
```

**File upload Form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
                <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
             </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it's only first line importing, but i need all data to import.

Comment: Can you upload any error received on the upload page?

Comment: No error, just success

Comment: Can you add a sample of your `.csv` ?